# Call API for list of objects in an arraylist Angular RxJs

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, rxjs, azure-devops-rest-api

I have an array list that contains list of objects. I want to call an API for all the objects in the list get the response and update back the object property. Please let me know what is the best way to handle this scenario. Tried with ForkJoin and For each but before completing all the request in the list, control is returned.

Basically I need to call first api which returns a resultset. For each items in the result set I need to call another api to get other details and update the items in the resultset.

Here is the code snippet

```
fetchReleaseDtl(strProjName: string) {
    let searchParams = new HttpParams();
    searchParams = searchParams.append('api-version', '7.0');
    console.log('about to fetch release details for ' + strProjName);
    return this.http
      .get<APIRlsDtlResp>(
        'https://vsrm.dev.azure.com/XXX/' + strProjName + '/_apis/release/releases',
        {
          headers: new HttpHeaders({
            'Authorization': 'Basic XXX'
          }),
          params: searchParams,
          responseType: 'json'
        }
      )
      .pipe(
        map(responseData => {
          console.log(responseData);
          let RlsDtlArray: APIRlsDtl[] = responseData.value;
          let RlsDtlDisp: APIRlsDtlDisp[] = [];
          for (let i = 0; i < RlsDtlArray.length; i++) {
            if (RlsDtlArray[i].releaseDefinition.name != '' && RlsDtlArray[i].description != ''
              && RlsDtlDisp.filter(e => e.name === RlsDtlArray[i].releaseDefinition.name
                && e.description === RlsDtlArray[i].description).length == 0) {
              var id = RlsDtlArray[i].id;
              var RlsDtl: APIRlsDtlDisp = {
                id: RlsDtlArray[i].id,
                name: RlsDtlArray[i].releaseDefinition.name,
                status: RlsDtlArray[i].status,
                description: RlsDtlArray[i].description.slice(0, 50),
                duration: 0
              };
              RlsDtlDisp.push(RlsDtl);
            }
          }
          return RlsDtlDisp;
        }),map((result) => {
          forkJoin(result.map(a=>{
            this.http.get<APIRlsExecDtl>('https://vsrm.dev.azure.com/XXX/XXX/_apis/release/releases/' + a.id, {
              headers: new HttpHeaders({
                'Authorization': 'Basic XXX='
              }),
              params: searchParams,
              responseType: 'json'
            }).subscribe((resp)=>{
                console.log(resp.environments[0].timeToDeploy);
                return result;
            })
          })).subscribe((b)=>{
            console.log('From Fork Join');
            console.log(b);
            console.log('About to return to component');
            return result;
          })
          /*result.forEach(element => {
            this.http.get<APIRlsExecDtl>('https://vsrm.dev.azure.com/XXX/XXX/_apis/release/releases/' + element.id, {
              headers: new HttpHeaders({
                'Authorization': 'Basic XXX'
              }),
              params: searchParams,
              responseType: 'json'
            }).subscribe((resp) => {
              console.log('Received resp');
              console.log(resp.environments[0].status);
              console.log(resp.environments[0].timeToDeploy);
              element.status = resp.environments[0].status;
              element.duration = parseInt(resp.environments[0].timeToDeploy);
            });
          })*/
          
        }),
        catchError(errorRes => {
          // Send to analytics server
          console.log(errorRes);
          return throwError(errorRes);
        })
      );
  }

Here is my model 

export interface APIRlsDtl{
    id:number;
    name:string;
    status:string;
    createdOn:string;
    modifiedOn:string;
    description:string;
    modifiedBy:{
      displayName:string
    };
    createdBy:{
      displayName:string
    };
    releaseDefinition:{
      name:string
    };
  }
  export interface APIRlsDtlResp{
    count:number;
    value:APIRlsDtl[]
  }
  export interface APIRlsDtlDisp{
    id:number;
    name:string;
    description:string;
    status:string;
    duration:number;
  }
  export interface RlsExecDtl{
    status:string
    timeToDeploy:string
  }
  export interface APIRlsExecDtl{
    id:number;
    environments:[RlsExecDtl]
  }
```

Comment: I am able to do this after splitting the functionality into 2 methods and using async await in angular. I feel that's the only way to do it for now.